# PHP/AJAX form submit issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, forms

First off, I suck at javascript... I copied some code which nearly does what I want - submitting a form and updating my database without a page refresh. The problem is that EVERY form on my page is now doing this. I only want this one particular form to call the function. Can someone help me out?

Javascript

```
<script>
              $(function () {
                $('form').bind('click', function (event) {
                // using this page stop being refreshing 
                event.preventDefault();

                  $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajax/post.php',
                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                    success: function () {
                      alert('Movie added to your list.');
                    }
                  });
                });
              });
            </script>
```

HTML Form

```
<form style="display: inline-block;">
                <input style="display: none" type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
                <input style="display: none" name="favorite" value="favorite" />
                <input style="color: #c0bfbf; padding: 0px 6px; background-color: transparent; border: 1px solid #c0bfbf; border-radius: 6px;" name="submit" type="submit" value="MY LIST"><?php } ?>
            </form>
```

I've tried multiple google searches, but can't fix the issue of every form on my page calling the function

Comment: `$('form')` — Well, you said every form there. If you want to be more specific then be more specific!

Comment: (You probably also want to trigger the request when the form is *submitted* instead of when it is clicked).

Comment: have a read of https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ . You might want to consider giving your `<form` an `id` to identify it

Comment: Worth noting also that `.bind()` is deprecated (and has been for many years) and was superseded by `.on()` - see https://api.jquery.com/bind/ for details

Comment: `<form id="form1" style="display: inline-block;">` ... `$('#form1').on('submit', function (event) {` . Or even use the shorthand `.submit()` - `$('#form1').submit(function (event) {` ...see https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>
         $(function () {
                $('#add').bind('click', function (event) {
                // using this page stop being refreshing 
                event.preventDefault();

                  $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajax/post.php',
                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                    success: function () {
                      alert('Movie added to your list.');
                    }
                  });
                });
              });
            </script>
```

**HTML Form**

```
<form id="add" style="display: inline-block;">
                <input style="display: none" type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
                <input style="display: none" name="favorite" value="favorite" />
                <input style="color: #c0bfbf; padding: 0px 6px; background-color: transparent; border: 1px solid #c0bfbf; border-radius: 6px;" name="submit" type="submit" value="MY LIST"><?php } ?>
            </form>
```

The problem was you have not mentioned `ID` to your form instead you simple called `$('form').bind` which means it will bind all inputs that are entered in `<form>` tag and will be send only submitted.

So now we have specified `id` to the form so script will run inputs only by form `ID`